# XSLT stylesheet provided is not producing the desired indentation in Firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xslt, xslt-1.0

The XSLT code provided below is not producing the desired indentation in the output of XML when I am using Firefox but it is working fine for chrome.

Here is the code:

```
var sourceXml = '<Environment name=“DEFAULT”>\n<ADFConnections>\n<Connection name="MapViewer”>\n<Attribute name="url”>\n</Connection>\n</ADFConnections>\n</Environment>'
      var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(sourceXml, 'application/xml');
      var xsltDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString([
            '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">',
            '  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>',
            '  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>',
            '  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">',
            '    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>',
            '  </xsl:template>',
            '</xsl:stylesheet>',
        ].join('\n'), 'application/xml'); 

        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);      
        var resultDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
        var resultXml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc);
```

In FireFox, it was showing like in single line

`<Environment name="DEFAULT"><ADFConnections><Connection name="MapViewer”> .....`

without any indentation. What I was doing wrong here where as it is working as expected in chrome with indentation.

Comment: when in doubt, [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/Element/output#indent) Firefox does not support the `indent` attribute for `xsl:output`

Comment: Basically Mozilla/Firefox does an input tree to result tree transformation and does not have support for the additional but optional, `xsl:output` defined serialization step.

Comment: As an additional note, these days in the browser with (sometimes incompatible) support for the ancient XSLT 1.0 version, you could also look into using SaxonJS 2 https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml for XSLT 3 support. Its documentation is at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html, it certainly has options to ensure you get a serialized result according to the `xsl:output` settings.

Comment: You can implement your own indentation by adding an indent parameter and increasing it when calling the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

To show you how you can use XSLT 3 with SaxonJS 2 and control the serialization in a cross-browser compatible way (note that the input XML you posted didn't seem to be well-formed XML so I corrected it a bit):

```js
const sourceXml = `<Environment name="DEFAULT">
  <ADFConnections>
    <Connection name="MapViewer">
      <Attribute name="url"></Attribute>
    </Connection>
  </ADFConnections>
</Environment>`;

const xsltCode = `<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <xsl:param name="indent" as="xs:boolean" static="yes" select="true()"/>
  <xsl:output _indent="{$indent}"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>`;

const result1 = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`transform(map{'stylesheet-text' : $xslt-code, 'source-node' : parse-xml($xml), 'delivery-format' : 'serialized' })?output`, null, { params: { 'xslt-code' : xsltCode, 'xml' : sourceXml } });

console.log(result1);

const result2 = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`transform(map{'stylesheet-text' : $xslt-code, 'source-node' : parse-xml($xml), 'delivery-format' : 'serialized', 'static-params' : map { QName('', 'indent') : false() } })?output`, null, { params: { 'xslt-code' : xsltCode, 'xml' : sourceXml } });

console.log(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/SaxonJS-2.6/SaxonJS2.js"></script>
```